# Generic function declaration

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I have declared my generic function as follows

```
public static Dictionary<TZerokey, Dictionary<TFirstKey, Dictionary<TSecondKey, TValue>>> 
    PivotCountry<TSource,TZeroKey, TFirstKey, TSecondKey, TValue>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,Func<TSource,TZeroKey> zerokeySelector, 
     Func<TSource, TFirstKey> firstKeySelector,
     Func<TSource, TSecondKey> secondKeySelector,
     Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TValue> aggregate)
{

    return null;//return value is not important for my question
}
```

I get a compile error

> > > TZerokey could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my declaration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit it. add code tag. It's not readable.

Comment: The compile error is quite self-explanatory to me...

Comment: that is the most disgusting function signature i've ever seen. seriously, my eyes hurt.

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet actually it isn't too far removed from most of the LINQ operations, if you've looked at the more exotic overloads; here's a nice one, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535047.aspx

Comment: @Marc: It's the three-level dictionary which is nasty though...

Comment: @fearofawhackplanet: I am sure I can beat that  :) Edit: Maybe not ;P

Comment: Isn't it in the specification (3.0) that nested generic types are discouraged? For instance a `List<T>` of `Dictionary<T,K>` is illegal.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment: Could you post the *exact* illegal declaration? Nested generic types are reasonably common - for example, `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`

Comment: Sorry, Jon, was more of a question, to be honest! I just recalled reading something along those lines (quite some time ago now) but it may have related to _use of_ generics. Either way, I'll do my best to try and hunt out what it was I read, just to clarify, when I have time this evening.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - you've got a typo: `TZerokey` in the return type, but `TZeroKey` in the type parameter. Note the difference of the case of the "K". So `TZerokey` isn't found, but `TZeroKey` would be.

Comment: great you could see the typo and milliosn of thanks for that. It was driving me crazy :)